# Continuous marquee start from very right to left

Tags: javascript, marquee

Does anyone know how to make the marquee start from very right to left according to the script below?

http://javascript.about.com/library/blctmarquee1.htm

http://javascript.about.com/library/blctmarquee2.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.. http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/_MARQUEE.html and http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_marquee_code.cfm.

```
<marquee>
Put your text here.
</marquee>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i would like to use javascript that i have used instead of marquee tag. Maybe can change some code in the javascript file to make it start from the very right? *I'm a beginner of javascript. Thanks

Comment: Check this links...
http://javascript.about.com/library/bltick2.htm
http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/image-scroller-windiv/
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/.. If you like the answer vote me up and click as answered..;P

Comment: I would appreciate your work if you could help me in modified the javascript by combining the one i gave and the one you gave. I'm beginner and just sucks in javascript. Could you mind to do me the flavour?

Comment: I dont mind to give a favor but i do mind if you expecting me to do your job. I believe the forum is to help us solving issues not expecting others to do work for us. Its ok if you dont appreciate my work since i just trying to help you. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: i hope you know that i did try but i just cant get it.as those link that u gave, i do had a look and try on them. But failed. its ok.nvm.thanks anyway.